# How to find net rows from sales and cancel rows using sql

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns mentioned below:

```
transaction_type  transaction_number  amount

Sale                 2016040433         50
Cancel               R2016040433       -50
Sale                 2016040434         50
Sale                 2016040435         50
Cancel               R2016040435       -50
Sale                 2016040436         50
```

I want to find net number of rows with only sales which does not include canceled rows.
(Using SQL Only).

Comment: And to confirm is the result you want for the example above 2?

Comment: I need correct sql query to solve this question

Comment: And how sane is your data, can you trust at most one cancel per sale, only sales can be cancelled etc, or is there junk and you are saying (number of ?distinct? Sale transaction_numbers for which there is no cancel record at all?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Please edit the question and provide the desired results.

Comment: If the transaction number of a canceled sale is the same as the sale but with the 'R' prefix and the absolute quantities are always the same , it is quite easy to figure out the net number of rows with no canceled sales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to count the sales and subtract the cancels (as suggested by your sample data), you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when transaction_type = 'Sale' then 1
                when transaction_type = 'Cancel' then -1
                else 0
            end)
from t;
```

Comment: Assuming the data is 'sane' this is the nicest approach, single table scan.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(transaction_type) FROM TBL_NAME GROUP BY count(transaction_type) HAVING transaction_type = 'Sale'
```

Just use the count function, and use HAVING with GROUP BY to filter

Answer (score 0):

The list of row

```
select transaction_number,  amount
from table 
where transaction_type ='Sale';
```

or sum

```
select  sum(amount)
from table 
where transaction_type ='Sale';
```

or count

```
select  count(*)
from table 
where transaction_type ='Sale';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the transaction number, which i assume is a unique identifier for each transaction, i would use it to count the net sale rows.

Assuming then than every Cancelled transaction number is 'R'+ Sales transact number, then the query i propose is the following:

```
WITH CancelledSales_CTE (transaction_type,  transaction_number,  amount)
AS
(
    SELECT transaction_type,  RIGHT(transaction_number, LEN(transaction_number) - 1),  amount
    FROM Sales
    WHERE transaction_type IS 'Cancel'
)
SELECT count(transaction_number)
FROM Sales
where transaction_number not in 
(select distinct transaction_number from CancelledSales_CTE )
```

CancelledSales_CTE contains the list of cancelled rows, with the transaction number of the relative sale.

The count coming from

```
   SELECT count(transaction_number)
    FROM Sales
    where transaction_number not in 
    (select distinct transaction_number from CancelledSales_CTE )
```

will exclude the transaction numbers which have been canceled